# QLineEdit setCornerWidget width

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit, qmenubar

I'm adding a QLineEdit to the menu bar with setCornerWidget. However, when setting a size with either setFixedWidth or setMinimumWidth, the QLineEdit is clipping through the window:

[image: Clipping QLineEdit]

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        menu = self.menuBar()

        search = QLineEdit(self)
        search.setFixedWidth(200)
        menu.setCornerWidget(search)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug, a workaround is to use a QWidget as a container:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        menu = self.menuBar()

        search = QLineEdit()
        search.setFixedWidth(200)

        container = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(container)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(search)

        menu.setCornerWidget(container)
```